# Refused to set ibus keyboard input method as root

Tags: ibus

On the Ubuntu12.04.3 LTS, I want to input chinese as **root user**, so I tried to configure **ibus** input framework. but it didn't work.

Two scenrios that I tried are following:

**1) By using gnome-terminal**

When I run *gnome-language-selector* as root user on the *gnome-terminal*, I get the output message upon setting **Keyboard input method system** option as **ibus**.

```
root@test-OptiPlex-9020:~# gnome-language-selector 
No system wide default defined just for locale en_US .
Use "all_ALL" quasi-locale and set IM.
update-alternatives: error: alternative /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/ibus for xinput-all_ALL not registered, not setting.
```

As you see above, When I'm in **root user** I couldn't set **ibus** at all.

**2) By using System setting**

1st. Current result

click the *language selector icon* for switching IMs.

2nd. Expected.

click the *keyboard input method system* as ibus.

After closing the gnome-language-selector dialog, relaunch that. It still shows that keyboard input method system option is always none.

Hope to fix this problem or bug!

PS. When I run `gnome-language-selector` as normal user, It works well.